# Is there any way to repeat whole describe() instead of it() (simple case) in cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I need to repeat whole describe() section in case of errors instead of repeating only it() function, because it depends on previous cases.

This is what I want to repeat

[image: (this is what i want to repeat)]

I've tried setting "retries" in cypress.json file, but how i said, it repeats every single step, not whole test case. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the retries option to the describe,

```
describe('...', { retires: 4 }, () => { ...
```